# How to use <abbr> to show dates (example from Facebook)

Tags: html

To display how much time is elapsed since the time the post was published, Facebook uses the  tag in this way:

```
<abbr title="Martedì 28 luglio 2015 alle ore 15.44"
      data-utime="1438091078"
      data-shorten="1"
      class="_5ptz timestamp livetimestamp">18 min</abbr>
```

**My question: which is the purpose of `data-utime` and `data-shorten`?**

Searching for them in Google I saw some pages speaking about JavaScript/JQuery: are those parameters intended to be used only with JavaScript? Or they serve other purposes?

Comment: Considering the fact that they're using custom data attributes they really shouldn't be using the HTML4 idiom of <abbr> and just using the HTML5 <time> element for marking up times instead... [but that's none of my business.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/but-thats-none-of-my-business)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will provide a brief overview about what's involved here.

### Element `abbr`

`abbr` is a valid HTML5 element which has only one attribute: `title`. As for [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/abbr):

> HTML provides a simple, straightforward way to mark abbreviations to
>   make sure that readers can understand them.

Also about [how to use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/HTML/Howto/Mark_abbreviations_and_make_them_understandable):

> The  HTML abbreviation element () identifies abbreviations and
>   acronyms, to help readers who aren't familiar with the abbreviation
>   and enable screen-reading software (used by visually-impaired users)
>   to read the text appropriately. The rule of thumb is, use the element
>   whenever possible.

### Data attributes

HTML5 allows the possibility for extending elements with attributes that are not part of the standard: [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes):

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be
>   associated with a particular element but need not have any defined
>   meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on
>   standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as
>   classList, non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or
>   setUserData.

So basically, `data-utime` and `data-shorten` is a way Facebook and other modules are using to display a more detailed description about dates.

#### Better using `<time>`

As some pointed out in comments, using `abbr` for this purpose for dates is not 100% correct as other tags can be used for such a purpose in HTML5. They could have used something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time):

```
<time datetime="2015-07-28 15:44">Martedì 28 luglio 2015 alle ore 15.44</time>
```

As it provides a better semantic and the goal of having a detailed version of the time is reached as well without need of data attribute `data-utime` to provide a machine readable timestamp.

**Display in tooltip** Remember also that `title` is a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title). So you can find it in `time` as well. In that way you can still display a tooltip on mouse hover.

Comment: Ok, it's all clear. I've used this solution: `<abbr title="{{ order.added }}"><time datetime="{{ order.added }}">{{ order.daysAgo }} fa</time></abbr>` as the tag `time` alone doesn't permit to pass with the mouse on the date to see the precise formatted date.

Comment: HTML5 has global attributes. `title` is one of these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes. See my edits :)